# Set value in 2D Numpy array based on row sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is this possible to accomplish with Numpy and with good performance?

Initial 2D array:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

If the sum of each row is less than 4, set the last item in each row to 1:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Divide each item in each row with the sum of each row and get this 
 result:

```
array([[0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0],
   [0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5],
   [0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the conditional assignment in a single line with some clever boolean indexing:

```
arr = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

arr[arr.sum(axis=1) < 4, -1] = 1
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

You can then divide each row by its sum like this:

```
arr = arr / arr.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0.   0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.5  0.   0.   0.5 ]
 [0.5  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.5 ]]
```

#### Explanation

Let's give the boolean index array `arr.sum(axis=1) >= 4` the name `boolix`. `boolix` looks like:

```
[ True False False]
```

If you slice `arr` with `boolix`, it will return an array with all of the rows of `arr` for which the corresponding value in `boolix` is `True`. So the result of `arr[boolix]` is an array with the `1`st and `2`nd rows of `arr`:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

In the code above, `arr` was sliced as `arr[boolix, -1]`. Adding a second index to the slice `arr[anything, -1]` makes the slice contain only the last value in each row (ie the value in the last column). So the `arr[boolix, -1]` will return:

```
[0 1]
```

Since these slices can also be assigned to, assigning `1` to the slice `arr[boolix, -1]` solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

<s>`numpy.where` can also be useful here to find the rows matching your condition</s>:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

a[np.sum(a,axis=1) < 4, -1] = 1
a = a/a.sum(axis=1)[:,None]

print(a)

# Output 
# [[0.   0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.  ]
#  [0.   0.   0.5  0.   0.   0.5 ]
#  [0.5  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.5 ]]
```

PS: Edited after @tel suggestion :)

Comment: Combining the row and column slices with `[x, -1]` is a nice idea. However, the `np.where` is completely pointless. You can remove it (and the extra work it's doing) and you get the same effect.

Comment: Oh right! For some reason I omited this. Thanks for pointing it out. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
x = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

x[:,-1][x.sum(axis=1) < 4] = 1
# array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
#   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
#  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

print(x/x.sum(axis=1)[:,None])
```

Output:

```
array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 ],
       [0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.5 ]])
```

Comment: Indexing twice (e.g. `x[a][b]` instead of `x[a, b]`) is usually a bad idea, as it may have unintended consequences (e.g. sometimes you can assign values this way, sometimes you can't)

Comment: @NilsWerner That is a good point that hadn't occurred to me when I was writing my answer (which did originally use `x[a][b]`). The issue is that while `x[a][b]` will return a view in many cases, sometimes it does return a copy instead, right?